# Spring Rest Request method 'GET ' not supported

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-restcontroller

I am trying to implement a Rest Api,the code seems correct and simple but i am getting this error and I can't figure out the problem.
[image]

The Log is outputting the following.

*2017-10-10 14:49:40.946  WARN 5750 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.s.web.servlet.PageNotFound             : Request method 'GET' not supported*

```
     @RestController("/report")
     @CrossOrigin(origins = { "http://localhost:4200" })
     public class JasperController {

       @RequestMapping(value = "/allReports", method = { RequestMethod.GET }, produces = "application/json")
         public String allReport() {
                        return "allReports!!!";
                    }

       @RequestMapping(value = "/supportedFields", method = { RequestMethod.GET }, produces = "application/json")
         public List<String> supportedFields() {
                        return Arrays.asList("name", "age", "address", "code", "contract");
        }

   }
```

Comment: Your allowed origin is "http://localhost:4200", and from browser you're calling from "http://localhost:8080". Ports doesnt match, so your origin is not allowed

Comment: I deleted it and the same error is still raising, i don't think the problem is the allowed origin.

Comment: Weird.. R U sure that your controller package is actually being scanned by Spring?

Comment: Yes i am sure, if I change one RequestMethod parameters from value = `"/allReports"` to `name="/allReports"` the error will disappear but if I enter /supportedFields in the browser it will call /allReports. And if  I change the two RequestMethod parameters to name instead of value then another exception is raised `There is already '/report' bean method
public java.lang.String controller.JasperController.allReport() mapped.`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's pretty simple. The value of `@RestController` is not the mapping for it. It's the mistake I've made a lot.
If you want a top-level mapping for all the methods in your controller, declare it with `@RequestMapping` on top of your controller class.

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/report")
public class JasperController {
```

Here is what the `value` on `@RestController` and `@Controller` is:

> The value may indicate a suggestion for a logical component name, to
>   be turned into a Spring bean in case of an autodetected component.